# How to Update JSONArray value on java

Tags: java, arrays

can anyone help me, i'am new on java programing

let say i have JSONArray with this data below :

```
[{
    "STATUSUPDATE": 0,
    "IDSERV": "2"
}, {
   "STATUSUPDATE": 0,
   "IDSERV": "3"
}, {
   "STATUSUPDATE": 0,
   "IDSERV": "1"
}]
```

How to update `STATUSUPDATE` to `1` in `IDSERV` `2`

How to update `STATUSUPDATE` to `2` in `IDSERV` `3`

and was trying to loop the data

```
for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++){
JSONObject itemArr = (JSONObject)array.get(j);
if(itemArr.get("IDSERV").equals(2)){
//should be itemArr.set(with new val) 
//but method *set* can cal; only on JSONArray not an JSONObject
//and looping the next one 
}
}
```

can anyone help me

Comment: You could use replace with a regex pattern.

Comment: can u direct me to the example @Olian?

Comment: just posted an answer. Take a look :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Here is the code:**

`array` is your `JSONArray`

```
for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject itemArr = (JSONObject)arr.get(i);
    if(itemArr.get("IDSERV").getAsString().equals("2")){
        itemArr.put("STATUSUPDATE", 1);
    }else if(itemArr.get("IDSERV").getAsString().equals("3")){
        itemArr.put("STATUSUPDATE", 2);
    }
}
```

Now, if you print `array` then you can see values are changed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, This approach will modify the value of `STATUSUPDATE` in `itemArr` right? the values in the original JSONArray `array` will the remain the same as before, right? @KrutiPatel

Answer (score 8):

`JSONArray` specific code:

**Output**

```
Initial array : [{"STATUSUPDATE":0,"IDSERV":"2"},{"STATUSUPDATE":0,"IDSERV":"3"},{"STATUSUPDATE":0,"IDSERV":"1"}]
Output array : [{"STATUSUPDATE":"1","IDSERV":"2"},{"STATUSUPDATE":"2","IDSERV":"3"},{"STATUSUPDATE":0,"IDSERV":"1"}]
```

**Code**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray("[{\"STATUSUPDATE\":0,\"IDSERV\":\"2\"},{\"STATUSUPDATE\":0,\"IDSERV\":\"3\"},{\"STATUSUPDATE\":0,\"IDSERV\":\"1\"}]");
        System.out.println("Initial array : " + array);

        for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(array.get(i).toString());
            if(jsonObject.get("IDSERV").equals("2")) {
                jsonObject.put("STATUSUPDATE", "1");
                array.put(i, jsonObject);
            }
            else if(jsonObject.get("IDSERV").equals("3")) {
                jsonObject.put("STATUSUPDATE", "2");
                array.put(i, jsonObject);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Output array : " + array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **regex** and **replaceAll**:

```
String json = ...
json.replaceAll("(?<=\"IDSERV\":\")\\d*(?=\")", new value);
```

The above will locate and replace ALL *IDSERV* fields.
If you only want to find and replace ONE of the *IDSERV* fields, change the `\\d` to `[]` and put the expected value to swap in between the braces.
 Ex: `[1]` will find and replace all values equal to `1`.

**EDIT1:**
Ok, you just edited the question.

This regex allows you to target a specific IDSERV and changes its STATUSUPDATE field.

```
(?<=:)\d*(?=,"IDSERV":"1")
```

In the above, change the number `1` to whatever value of IDSERV you want to look for.

In java that would be:

```
String json = ...
json.replaceAll("(?<=:)\\d*(?=,\"IDSERV\":\"1\")", new value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used replacing some fields its decimal values to zero on user role. Its working

```
shimpment=shimpment.replaceAll("\"shipmentValue\":[0-9]+.[0-9]+", "\"shipmentValue\":0.00");
shimpment=shimpment.replaceAll("\"price\":[0-9]+.[0-9]+", "\"price\":0.00");
shimpment=shimpment.replaceAll("\"tax\":[0-9]+.[0-9]+", "\"tax\":0.00");
```