# How to update one cell in a json file

Tags: java, json

I have (java) class of user with some field (username , type,password,country) and json file with the data. 
for example -

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "john",
      "type": "admin",
      "password": "potato",
      "country": "united states",
    },
    {
      "username": "lisa",
      "type": "normal",
      "password": "chips123",
      "country": "spain",
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way I can give json a particular user object, rather than an array of all users, to update only that specific user data?
and to add more user rather than send new array with all the old and the new users?
The purpose of the program is to eventually build a server, and I have to save all the data in the json file and update them.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the question.  Wouldn't the array with one user data be same as what you want?

Comment: Hi, I have to save all users in such a way that in the json file they will appear under one array named "users" as in the example.
But when I want to update the details of one user, I want to find a way to send only the object of this specific user to json, rather than send all the array users.
It seems to me less efficient each time to update the entire array, instead of just one cell that representativea specific user, am I wrong?

Comment: For example, if I want to update the user called lisa, I want to send to json the lisa object, not the entire array of both the Lisa and john objects.

Comment: I believe the answer you're looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913318/how-to-update-jsonarray-value-on-java)

Comment: You can also read about adding new elements in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143363/add-data-to-jsonobject)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Update JSONArray value on java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913318/how-to-update-jsonarray-value-on-java)