# Changing a string in a jsonArray without adding extra slashes before quotes

Tags: java, json, string

I have a JSONArray object and sometimes it has elements that contain \u0000 chars. I'm trying to remove them by converting the element into a string, removing the unwanted chars and adding it back to the JSONArray. The problem is that I get extra slashes before the quotes that I don't want.

Is there any way to manipulate the content of the array without getting those slashes?

My code is like the following (queryArray is my old JSONArray, and I'm trying to create a new one with the cleaned strings):

```
JSONArray newQueryArray = new JSONArray();

for (Object jsonObj : queryArray){
    String sqlValue = jsonObj.toString();
    sqlValue = sqlValue.replace("\u0000", "");
    sqlValue = sqlValue.replace("\\u0000", "");
    sqlValue = sqlValue.replace("\\\"","\"");
    newQueryArray.put(sqlValue);
}
```

I get for example the following JSON:

```
  "query": [
    "{\"Line 0\":\"4\"}"
  ],
```

while I wish to get:

```
  "query": [
    {
      "Line 0": "4"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: You should be able to follow this and do what you want https://stackoverflow.com/q/38913318/360211